# Can jquery tell me which image is shown when .cycle stops?

Tags: jquery

I have 5 images inside a single div and I'm using jquery's .cycle plugin to cycle through them. Is there a way jquery can tell me which image the cycle stopped on?

Heres my html...

```
    <div id="slot1">
        <li id="reel1a"><img src="reel1a.jpg" /></li>
        <li id="reel1b"><img src="reel1b.jpg" /></li>
        <li id="reel1c"><img src="reel1c.jpg" /></li>
        <li id="reel1d"><img src="reel1d.jpg" /></li>
        <li id="reel1e"><img src="reel1e.jpg" /></li>
    </div>
```

Comment: You could probably check to see which one has an opacity/visibility.

Comment: $('#slot1').index($(this).children().is(':visible'));

Answer (score 0):

You can find out with [jQuery's ":visible" selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/). The docs say:

> During animations that hide an element, the element is considered to be visible until the end of the animation. During animations to show an element, the element is considered to be visible at the start at the animation.

With your example HTML, you'd want to use the function invocation from Torr3nt's comment:

```
$('#slot1').index($(this).children().is(':visible'));
```

This will return the position of the element that is currently visible (see [the "Return Values" section](http://api.jquery.com/index/) of index()'s docs).